# Marketing Cloud journeys from MC connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

I had a question about how the journey created using salesforce data from cloud connect works. When a lead gets into the journey the user data is stored in a journey DE .So, what happens if the lead is removed from the sales cloud during the lead in the journey. Does this affect or is it so that all the user data are taken from DE once the lead is in journey. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.... "it depends".
If your journey is relying alone on the journey data, and you don't have any contact deletion process in place, the contact will just continue through the journey. If there are e.g. decision steps or emails utilising contact data, you will most probably experience issues. However it all depends on the way your data is structured in SFMC. Regardless, removing the lead os removed from MC, there are no measures in place, which would automatically kick the contact out of the journey.